# Multiple PCI-E ports without a switch

Tags: raspberry-pi, switch, pci-express

I was just thinking of designing an IO board for cm4 but when I was deciding a PCI-E switch I came across this image (see the lower part of the image):

[image]

I saw that all the devices were having a common connection. Is it really possible?
(note the context is PCI-E, not PCI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PCI Express uses dedicated, point-to-point links throughout.

Logically, there is a bus (for legacy PCI compatibility), but physically it needs to be dedicated or switched.

You cannot connect a PCIe lane to more than two devices. But you can use PCIe switches to increase the total number of lanes to connect more devices.

Comment: @Mokubai Absolutely - *physically it needs to be dedicated **or switched***.

Comment: @Mokubai I was deliberately using *lanes* as very often, multi-lane *links* can be split and their lanes arranged differently. Lanes are atomic.

Comment: @Zac67 , so the conclusion is it is not possible.

Comment: @user135142 yes, PCIe does not allow lanes to be split in a "parallel connection". If the bottom of your image said "PCI" rather than PCIe, then I would believe it. In my experience the top part of your image is correct, the bottom is not allowed and would at best make for an unreliable connection.

Comment: Your bottom image might be a reinterpretation of the theoretical layout achieved by the Switch, as that is essentially what the switch allows, but you 100% have to have the switch do that job.

Comment: @user135142    In fact, judging by the caption under the image where you found it at https://computer.howstuffworks.com/pci-express.htm which states `Devices using PCI share a common bus, but each device using PCI Express has its own dedicated connection to the switch.` I believe that the bottom image is mislabelled and should actually state just PCI, not PCI Express.

Comment: so it's a problem with image, right?

Comment: Seems like it - as @Mokubai states, the bottom image is mislabeled as *PCI Express* which should be *Conventional PCI*. Also note the title *PCI Express PCI Comparison* which doesn't match the labels.